# Why can Avahi `.local` domains not be resolved over a VPN?

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, dns, avahi

I have a homelab setup with a few Raspberries Pi that use [Avahi](https://www.avahi.org/) for service announcement - I can ssh to them with `ssh pi@<hostname>.local` instead of having to remember individual IP addresses. In particular, note that this not only works from my laptop, but also from the Pis themselves - that is, if I am ssh'd to `pi1`, I can successfully `ssh pi@pi2.local`.

I recently set up a [Wireguard VPN](https://docs.pivpn.io/wireguard/) running on one of the Pis to allow me to access my homelab even when away from home. When using this VPN on my laptop, I'm able to ssh to a pi with `ssh pi@<LAN-IP-address-of-pi>`, but *not* with `ssh pi@<hostname>.local`.

Why is that? My (admittedly basic) understanding of VPNs is that they operate by making your connection behave "as if" it originated from the VPN server. If that is the case, why would I get different ssh behaviour via a VPN than from the VPN server itself? Or, if that is not the case, how is it incorrect?

My intuition is that DNS resolution does not go via the VPN - when I compare the results of `dig pi.local` from my VPN'd-laptop and from the VPN server, I get different results (not sharing the whole payload since I don't know enough about networking and security to know what is safe to share and what is not):

- from my laptop, the `;SERVER` line references `8.8.8.8` (which I believe is a Google-owned standard DNS server, which would correctly "not know about" my Pi's IP address on the LAN)
- from the VPN server, the `;SERVER` line references the LAN IP address of my LAN's [pi-hole](https://pi-hole.net/)

Interestingly, though, neither response actually contains an `ANSWER` section or the Pi's actual IP address.

Comment: `hostname.local` is a DNS entry that resolves to an IP address. This means somewhere on your current network, there must be something that knows what hostname.local means. In your home network, you will have something that makes this work, but through VPN you do not. You can place this in your hosts file and it will work too. Alternatively, if you use Windows' VPN client, you can specify an additional DNS server on the connection so that the hostname can be aquired.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My intuition is that DNS resolution does not go via the VPN

Whether it does or not, that doesn't affect mDNS (Avahi). The `.local` names are resolved by a separate mDNS resolver, not using the standard unicast DNS resolver, and the whole point of mDNS is that it works without DNS servers; it works by broadcasting a query packet to the entire local subnet.

*(Multicasting, technically, but as it's link-scoped you can pretend it's the same as a local broadcast.)*

You shouldn't actually get *any* "ANSWER" responses out of `dig whatever.local`, even if Pi-Hole is being referenced. In case you get a response from the Pi-Hole, that's not Avahi/mDNS – that's just regular DNS. (Home routers implement local DNS by gathering hostnames from DHCP lease requests; but they usually do not gather mDNS advertisements, even if you happen to have `.local` as the DNS domain – which you shouldn't.)

> Why is that? My (admittedly basic) understanding of VPNs is that they operate by making your connection behave "as if" it originated from the VPN server. If that is the case, why would I get different ssh behaviour via a VPN than from the VPN server itself? Or, if that is not the case, how is it incorrect?

More generally than that, VPNs operate by *connecting you* to a network together with the VPN server. You could say they form a virtual LAN across the Internet. They *don't* necessarily masquerade your connections or make it look like you're connecting "as if" the VPN server – that's done separately if needed. (Masquerading is not a VPN-specific feature, it's the exact same NAT that would be used with physical LANs.)

*(That's the real difference between VPNs and proxies, aside from the OSI layer distinction. A proxy server's main purpose is to relay requests so that they come "as if" from the proxy. A VPN's main purpose is to build a virtual network.)*

Most VPN types don't directly connect you to the VPN server's *existing* network, however, but create a **new** one. You have two separate networks – the VPN-created "LAN" and the physical LAN – with the VPN server acting *as a router* in-between. Like a physical router would have `eth0 eth1 eth2` or LAN/WAN, your VPN server routes between `eth0` (the LAN) and `wg0` (the WireGuard VPN).

Just as with two physical subnets separated by a router, the two can exchange regular (unicast) packets between devices, but a router will not relay *local broadcasts* between subnets, nor will it relay link-scope multicasts that mDNS uses. So when your VPN client sends out an mDNS multicast query – it only goes as far as the "local" subnet between VPN client and VPN server. It is never forwarded from the server's wg0 interface out through eth0 or whatever else. To make this work, the VPN server would probably need to run its own avahi-daemon in "relay" or "reflector" mode, where it proxies received mDNS queries to other interfaces and sends replies back.

Additionally, many VPN connections don't actually emulate a "broadcast-capable" interface like Ethernet, making broadcast and multicast packet usage impossible in the first place. WireGuard in particular forms a kind of "point-to-multipoint" network where it's more like a bunch of one-to-one connections under the hood – all of them are hidden behind a single wg0 interface, but internally it uses AllowedIPs to decide which peer to send each packet to, and it makes no exception for broadcasts or multicasts. Roughly the same applies to OpenVPN in its default "tun" mode (or most anything else that uses "tun" interfaces).

But some other VPNs, such as OpenVPN in "tap" mode, as well as software like Tinc or ZeroTier, *do* emulate an Ethernet-like network with layer-2 addressing, allowing them to handle multicasts and broadcasts in a more conventional way. In fact, they mostly just emulate regular Ethernet, allowing the VPN server to *bridge* the VPN and LAN interfaces instead of routing between them. If you set up a "bridge" VPN, then connected VPN clients will in fact become part of the same LAN subnet as local devices and will automatically be able to see each other's mDNS broadcasts.

*(The downside is, also, that they will see each other's mDNS broadcasts – and ARP broadcasts, and Dropbox broadcasts, and UPnP/SSDP broadcasts, and NetBIOS broadcasts, and WS-Discovery broadcasts, and a whole lot of background noise.)*

Comment: Wow - thank you for an astonishingly comprehensive response! I will need to re-read it a few times to really learn all that I can from it. Do you have any references or guides for networking that you recommend? In particular, I don't understand what it means to "add a network" - I am aware that there are multiple interfaces(?) listed from `ifconfig`, but (beyond the fact that `eth0` and `wlan0` presumably represent an Ethernet port and a WiFi connection) I don't know what they _mean_, or how requests/packets/etc. are routed to the appropriate one.

Comment: I don't really have any good links; I've heard Cisco has a lot of learning materials, I think (CCNP etc)? What I'd recommend, though, is focussing more on general concepts first – routing tables, netmasks, interfaces, link vs network layers (or L2 vs L3 in OSI terms), what a MAC address really does – and not too much on Linux specific resources. Your PiVpn is a router that has two networks, is the main thing; the router being Linux-based is secondary. If it's a homelab, I'd buy a Mikrotik router, a cheap used Cisco router, etc. set it up with two or three Ethernets, etc.